# Moving divs + array with text in jquery, IE misbehaving

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Please see the following website (http://www.intra-interieur.be/www) in Firefox, chrome, safari, .. It works fine. Then, open it in IE (7 or 8, doesn't matter). It doesn't really work :-). You can view the source of whatever you want, but here are the important things.

I think the array with text that is being replaced is causing the other problems (the moving divs not functioning correctly).

```
$('#menu ul li.home').addClass('active');

var msgs = [ "ga hier", "bekijk dit", "misschien dit", "of zelfs hier" ];
var msgs_length = msgs.length;

$("#menu ul li a").click(function () { 
     $('#menu ul li.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
     $('.go', this).text("u bent hier");

     $("#menu ul li a").not(this).each(function(i) {
         $('.go', this).text(msgs[i % msgs_length]);
     });
});
```

And the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#home" class="panel">home / <span class="go">u bent hier</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfloats"></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#about" class="panel">over intra / <span class="go">ga hier</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfloats"></li>
        <li class="cases"><a href="#cases" class="panel">projecten / <span class="go">bekijk dit</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfloats"></li>
        <li class="photos"><a href="#photos" class="panel">foto's / <span class="go">misschien dit</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfloats"></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#contact" class="panel">contact / <span class="go">of zelfs hier<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone see the problem? I really can't figure out why IE is behaving so badly. Of course, it's IE but :-)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't float your `LI`s and use "clearfloats". Actually, don't style your LIs at all.

Style the A-tags instead. Use `width` + `margin-left`, `display:block` to achieve the same appearance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i usually don't do it like this. I did do it like this because otherwise IE7 messed it all up. Do you think that's the source of the problem? I know my ways around perfect styling & xhtml'ing, i work in a webdesign bureau..